# Can I use Loop concepts in protractor searching elements by Xpath?

Tags: javascript, protractor, automated-tests, angular7

I have some similar insights in webpage and to optimize out the code can I use looping inside protractor code.
like for example if have 5 insights in webpage and to write code manually for all 5 insights will be quite difficult for the code to exeute. 
So if I'm searching elements by their Xpath so can I use loop in between them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! you can use the loop in your protractor scripts to go through the elements based on xpath locator.

e.g.

```
for (int i=1; i<5; 1++){
element(by.xpath('html\div[1]\div\div[2]\span['+i+']'));
//do whatever the operation is required on the element
}
```

But there is a suggestion, it's better to use ng-model, css or id selectors instead of xpath because there is likely a chance that xpath dynamically updates and in that case it will always require modification in the scripts.